# Display Autocomplete list based on a Cell Range

Tags: c#, autocomplete, vsto

I'm trying to do an Excel Add-In and I would like that, in a worksheet that I'm creating, I could select a cell (or a range of cell) that, once you start typing on it (or them), a dropdown-like with possible matches for the typed characters.

Is this possible to do it programmatically?

The closest that I got to achieve this is through the **Validation** object of the Cell, but a dropdown-like list of options is not displayed just, as you could imagine, I get to display a message indicating that the text is not valid.

As always, thanks in advance!